# Difference between orientation sensor and magnetic field sensor on Android?

Tags: android, orientation, magnetometer, digital-compass

Does anyone know the difference between the orientation sensor and magnetic field sensor on Android?

My understanding:

- orientation => digital compass
- magnetic field => magnetometer

Since I've read that magnetometer is synonymous with digital compass I'm a little bit confused. What are they really?

Comment: good. I was looking for the same question and have little doubt. Now I am sure of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The magnetic field sensor is the compass.

The orientation sensor is a combination between the magnetic field sensor, and gravity sensors. It tells you the angle of the phone relative to the ground (pitch and roll) and the direction (compass).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This means orientation isn't a seperate sensor but a combined result of two others? 

The reason why a ask is that I wrote an app which calculates the orientation on two ways.
1) orientation sensor  
2) magnetic field sensor + accelerator sensor

The values aren't completly different but the second approach is much more accurate. Any guess why?

Comment: @Guffa, i doubt if accelerometer is really essential, since the data got from the magnetic field sensor is also in 3 dimensions, why cant it get yaw,pitch and roll just using the mag data?

Comment: @zhangxaochen: The magnetic field is a lot weaker than the gravitational field, so you get a more accurate reading from the accelerometer.